# ¿Cómo ordeno mis scss con Angular CLI (5)?

Tags: css, angular, angular5, scss, angular-cli

Tengo varios componentes como son Material y Flex, pero me gustaría que el orden de según **prioridad** css fuese:

1. Css de mis componentes
2. Css global de mi proyecto
3. Css material
4. Css flex

Estoy buscando pero no encuentro una solución que me funcione.

He probado lo siguiente pero no sé usarlo bien:

> angular-cli.json

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "../node_modules/@angular/material/*.scss",
          "styles.scss",
          "./redes/components/*/**.scss"
        ]
      },
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los CSS de los componentes siempre tendrán máxima prioridad al ser los más restrictivos, no hace falta que los añadas al fichero `angular-cli.json`

Los demás ficheros tienes que ponerlos en el orden inverso de importancia, desde los más generales a los más específicos.

Si piensas que no funcionan, recuerda que tienes que reiniciar el servidor (si estás usando `ng serve` para probar) o rehacer completamente el build para que se apliquen los cambios